# Usage of NPM sticky-session with Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, npm, https, cluster-computing, sticky-session

How we can use sticky-session with Cloudflare?
The main principle of sticky-session is that it takes the IP of the user, and then balances it to workers.
But if we use Cloudflare we will get proxied IPs of Cloudflare, which makes sticky-session useless, because IPs mostly will be the same.
Is there any fix for this problem?

I have tried to rewrite the code by using HTTPS, instead of net, but came to a dead end.